# Can't send large file over TCP

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send file over TcpClient:

```cs
byte[] fileBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes("someFile");

stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x2A });
stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)name.Length));
stream.Write(name);
stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileBuffer.Length));
stream.Write(fileBuffer);
stream.Flush();
```

And trying to read this data and write it to new file:

```cs
byte[] nameSizeBytes = new byte[2];
stream.Read(nameSizeBytes);
short nameSize = BitConverter.ToInt16(nameSizeBytes);

byte[] nameBytes = new byte[nameSize];
stream.Read(nameBytes);
string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nameBytes);

byte[] dataSizeBytes = new byte[4];
stream.Read(dataSizeBytes);
int dataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataSizeBytes);

byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataSize];
stream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataSize);

using (FileStream fileStream = new(Path.Combine(directory, name), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    fileStream.Write(dataBuffer);
}
```

Reading the file at the beginning works as expected, but when reading the stream, 1000-50000 bytes of data are successfully written, but after that there are many zeros that bring the file size down to the size of the original file

**UPD:** I've noticed that the number of trailing zeros changes randomly on every write attempt.

Comment: `stream.Read` might not read all the bytes you need. You probably want `stream.ReadExactly`

Comment: yep, the data is sent in chunks. you should create a while loop. (check the result of the Read( function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ReadExactly` instead of `Read`, otherwise you may only get a partial read.

```cs
byte[] nameSizeBytes = new byte[2];
stream.ReadExactly(nameSizeBytes);
short nameSize = BitConverter.ToInt16(nameSizeBytes);

byte[] nameBytes = new byte[nameSize];
stream.ReadExactly(nameBytes);
string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nameBytes);

byte[] dataSizeBytes = new byte[4];
stream.ReadExactly(dataSizeBytes);
int dataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataSizeBytes);

byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataSize];
stream.ReadExactly(dataBuffer, 0, dataSize);

using (FileStream fileStream = new(Path.Combine(directory, name), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    fileStream.Write(dataBuffer);
}
```

A more efficient implementation might do

```cs
using (FileStream fileStream = new(Path.Combine(directory, name), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    int read;
    while (dataSize > 0 && 
           (read = input.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(buffer.Length, dataSize))) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        dataSize -= read;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things going on here:

1. `File.ReadAllBytes` is a bad idea for large files
2. you **must** respect the return value from `Read` and read in a loop until you have the *expected* amount of data - there is absolutely no guarantee that you get all the data in one go; this applies even when reading the preamble/length-prefix bytes
3. `BitConverter` is CPU-endian; you should not use that in most cases (prefer things like `BinaryPrimitives` which has endian-specific APIs)

The second one is why you're getting zeros/garbage: you gave it a huge buffer, and it read *some* data; `Read` simply has to read *at least one byte* or report an EOF. It does not fill your buffer.